# How we can create similarity matrix from dictionar?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a dict as following:

```
dic = {a1: [a,b,c], b1:[b,k,l]}.
```

I want to create a similarity matrix for each key's value list. for example, for key  `a1`, I want to compute similarities between `(a,b), (a,c) and (b,c)` using suppose method `f`. `f((a,a)) = 1`.  We can do it by creating a vector and indexing its element by the value of similarity between `(a,b), (a,c) and (b,c)` and repeat the same procedure to b i.e. `(b,a), (b,b), and (b,c)` and so on. but It is not necessary as the similarity of `(b,a) =(a,b)`. so how can solve that?how can create such matrix? 
the same way will be applied then to each key of the dic (i.e. b1 etc)

Comment: I don't see the link between your procedure applied to a `(a,b), (a,c) and (b,c)` and your procedure applied to b `(b,a), (b,b), and (b,c)`. Could you try to clarify your question ?

Comment: @louis_guitton suppose when i compare a and b (i.e. (a,b)) by method f the result is 0.7. Then we can conclude that also the simiarity between b and a (i.e. (b,a)) is 0.7. Just suppose f as jaccard similarity

Comment: sure. What I don't understand is the rest of the terms. Didn't you mean you're looking on the one hand at `(a,a) (a,b) and (a,c)` and on the other hand at `(b, a), (b, b), (b, c)` ?

Comment: yes. I want to build a matrix from those simialrities without repeating the same comparaison ((a,b) and (b,a)) just to save time.  this matrix is symetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `f` is expensive and not vectorizable, you could use `np.tri` and friends along the lines of

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from operator import itemgetter as iget
>>> 
# set up an example
>>> a1, b1 = 'a1', 'b1'
>>> a, b, c, k, l = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 3))
>>> dic = {a1: [a,b,c], b1: [b,k,l]}
>>> f = np.dot
>>> 
# do the computation
>>> RES = {}
>>> for k, v in dic.items():
...     N = len(v)
...     res = np.ones((N, N))
...     I, J = np.triu_indices_from(res, 1)
...     res[I, J] = np.fromiter(map(f, iget(*I.tolist())(v), iget(*J.tolist())(v)), float, N*(N-1)//2)
...     np.copyto(res, res.T, where=np.tri(*res.shape, -1, bool))
...     RES[k] = res
... 
# check
>>> RES
{'a1': array([[  1., 108., 122.],
       [108.,   1., 120.],
       [122., 120.,   1.]]), 'b1': array([[ 1., 42., 66.],
       [42.,  1., 20.],
       [66., 20.,  1.]])}
```

Instead of `map(f, iget(...` you could also use `itertools.starmap(f, itertools.combinations(v, 2))`.

Comment: what do you mean by expensive and not vectorizabe. By the way i get an exception np.copyto(res, res.T, where=np.tri(*res.shape, -1, bool))
SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression

Comment: @bib If f is cheap it is simpler and faster to just call it twice. If f is vectorizable then this can be exploited also resulting in simpler and faster code. The error you are getting suggests you are on an ancient python version. As a workaround try `ny, nx = res.shape` and replace `*res.shape` with `ny, nx`

Comment: Thank you  your solution is working well for my. But can you please explain me res[I, J] = np.fromiter(map(f, iget(*I.tolist())(v), iget(*J.tolist())(v)), float, N*(N-1)//2)
...     np.copyto(res, res.T, where=np.tri(*res.shape, -1, bool)). Because i need to play arround the dictionary by giving for example the value of a1 as list of tuple. Just comment your solution.

Comment: @bib well, the first of these lines uses the indices I, J to select for example at the first iteration (a, a, b) and (b, c, c ) using operator.itemgetter beacuse in my experience for bulk lookup it is faster than retrieving the elements one by one. map essentially zips these and applies f to get f(a, b), f(a, c) and f(b,c). On python 3 map produces an iterator which is where the np.fromiter comes in. On python 2 it should be possible to leave out fromiter, because map returns a list. I and J on the l.h.s. of the assignment ensure that the values are stored in the correct locations in res.

Comment: The next line simply copies the upper triangle to the lower triangle. As I suggest in the answer you could replace map(f, iget(*I.` etc with `itertools.starmap(` etc. That may be easier to read and also possibly faster.